# Frequency limit when applying Holt-Winters model to daily dataset

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to use the Holt-Winters model to forecast the daily pollution rates of some cities. I have almost 4 years of daily data available and would like to make a prediction for the next 180 days.

For simplicity, I'll make a quick time series with rnorm() to elaborate my problem.

```
myts <- ts(rnorm(1461), start=2016, frequency = 365)
```

(from what I've read on the internet, this is how you make a daily time series with ts().)

[image]

Training dataset: `traints <- window(myts, end=c(2019, 181))`

I tried to fit a Holt-Winters additive model by:

```
fit1 <- hw(traints, seasonal='additive')
```

but it gave an error:

```
Error in ets(x, "AAA", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, gamma = gamma, phi = phi,  : 
  Frequency too high
```

When searching around it seems that ets() has a frequency limit of 24. I've read that Holt-Winters can be used for daily data so how would I work around this frequency limit to make a model(other than switching to ARIMA models)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using Holt-Winters for your data is that you need to estimate 365 initial states for the seasonality component. This will overfit hopelessly. So don't use smoothing with such long periods.

[Rob Hyndman's suggestion](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) is to model the seasonality using Fourier terms, and possibly using ARIMA for residuals. `auto.arima()` will happily do this for you.

Comment: Yes thankyou, I'll look into that. Also, what type of data does Holt-Winters models usually use to make forecasts? (monthly? weekly?)

Comment: Holt-Winters is really made for shorter seasonal periods. You could use it for daily time series - as long as your seasonality is the *weekly* one, with a period of 7 days. It's commonly used for monthly or quarterly series, where periods are of length 12 or 4.

Comment: I see. Thankyou